# Is it possible to order related entries by relevance of tags?

Tags: entries, relations, tags, sorting

I have a set of entries which each have 0 or more tags (no limit). For each entry, I am aiming to display 3 'related entries', related by the tags field.

e.g. If entry 1 is tagged with 'apples', 'bananas' and 'pears', then the first results returned would be entries with all 3 tags, followed by 2, followed by just one, then those with none of the tags.

Is this possible? I can't see anything in the documentation about ordering by relevance of the 'relatedTo' parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using [Search](https://craftcms.com/docs/searching) because it already orders by relevance. You could define the search query using the tags. Make sense?

Comment: When this question was asked I don't think the `score` parameter was available, but this has been the option we have been using since that Craft update!

Comment: Nice Mike! Glad you have a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a plugin called [Similar](https://github.com/aelvan/Similar-Craft) that does exactly this. Give it a go.